# Remove duplicate lines from Ansible variable

Tags: filter, ansible, duplicates, output

I need to achieve two things.

1. Remove duplicate entries from ansible variable called install_loc
2. Remove any empty blank lines from install_loc.

Below is how install_loc variable is constructed.

```
   - set_fact:
       install_loc: "{{ install_loc | default('') + item.split( )[4] | dirname + '\n' }}"
     loop: "{{ fdet }}"
```

Below are the contents of install_loc after writing it to a file.

```
/app/logs/scripts
/app/logs/mrt
/app/logs/com
/app/logs/exe

/app/logs/scripts
/app/logs/mrt
/app/logs/com
/app/logs/exe

/app/logs/scripts
/app/logs/mrt
/app/logs/com
/app/logs/exe
```

As you can see the variable as newlines as well as duplicate entries.

Desired output should be as below. Note: Order does not matter:

```
/app/logs/scripts
/app/logs/mrt
/app/logs/com
/app/logs/exe
```

I tried

```
   - set_fact:
       install_loc: "{{ install_loc | unique }}"
```

But i get distorted text like below:

```
set([u'\n', u'/', u'.', u'1', u'0', u'3', u'2', u'C', u'E', u'G', u'F', u'I', u'N', u'a', u'c', u'e', u't', u'i', u'm', u'o', u'o', u'n', u's', u's', u'r', u'u', u't', u'x'])
```

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 4):

The solution:

```
- set_fact:
    install_loc: "{{ install_loc.split('\n') | unique | select | list }}"
```

Explanation:

- `install_loc.split('\n')` - Split the `install_loc` by newlines
- `unique` - Remove duplicates
- `select` - Get rid of empty or null values
- `list` - Convert from a Python "generator" to a list

If you want a single string (as the input) replace `list` by `join('\n')`.

Comment: This makes install_loc as a list instead of string and when written to a file looks like this:

['/app/logs/scripts', '/app/logs/mrt', '/app/logs/com', '/app/logs/exe'] 

when i want it to look like

/app/logs/scripts
/app/logs/mrt
/app/logs/com
/app/logs/exe

Comment: If i remove list from the command it prints <generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7fd724de7460> in the file with inline module

Comment: See the last line of my answer.

Comment: Thanks @mhurter this answers my question. However i m not able to read this variable in a different play. I posted a new query here if you could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959397/unable-to-read-set-fact-variable-in-different-ansible-play